# How to pronounce "ask yourself" /æsk jɔːrˈself/?

Tags: pronunciation

ok, now the phrase "**ask yourself**" is pronounced as `/æsk jɔːrˈself/`.

My question is that, do we link `k` & `j` together.

1st option, we could link `k` & `j` since `j` is a semivowel. So we could say `/æs kj ɔːrˈself/`.

2nd option, we could hold the `k` like a glottal stop since `j` is a consonant. So we could say `/æs? jɔːrˈself/`.

So, **which one is the right way of saying  "ask yourself"?**

Comment: You can certainly blend the two sounds, KJ (as in the word "cure" -- as cure self). But it's not "wrong" to speak the words slowly and distinctly, without such blending.

Comment: @TRomano, sometimes I feel like people omit /j/ so it sounds like /æskɔːr/

Comment: It depends on the accent, mostly. The british transcription is /ɑːsk jɔːˈsɛlf/. The best way is to listen to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Well you may want to try [this site](http://youglish.com/search/%22ask%20yourself%22). They have more than 740 pronunciations of 'ask yourself':

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think of any better tip than listening to the sound examples.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better than the second. We don't usually use a glottal stop in clusters like /sC/ (C -> consonant like t, k etc).

([This paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-international-phonetic-association/article/abs/glottalization-of-english-p-t-k-and-ta-reexamination/02D1198CA6D55D6588EFEC701735A09D) might be helpful.)